# Why '&' here means reference?

Tags: c++, reference

I'm reading *C++ Primer* and it really confused me when I read this:

```cpp
int odd[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
int even[] = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};
//return a pointer, which points an array with 5 int
decltype(odd) *arrPtr(int i)
{
    return (i % 2) ? &odd : &even;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "odd: " << odd << endl;
    cout << "even: " << even << endl;
    cout << arrPtr(3);
}
```

The result is:

```
odd: 0x472010
even: 0x472030
0x472010
```

What puzzles me is why there is a need for &. I mean, is it necessary to add a '&'?

I tried to delete & like this:

```cpp
return (i % 2) ? odd : even;
```

And it just doesn't work:

```
[Error] cannot convert 'int*' to 'int (*)[5]' in return
```

Here's what I thought:

It can't be 'address of odd', for it will become a second-order pointer.
**So it must be a reference.(This is my opinion)**

So the question is, why must it be a reference?

Can anyone explain this for me? Any answer is welcomed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `&` here means take address of variable, which actually creates pointer to pointer

Comment: @IłyaBursov there is no pointer to pointer

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number ok, pointer to array, and arrays almost always can be considered as pointers

Comment: @IłyaBursov - Except the exceptions to "always" are so dramatic and bug-inducing that it's best to never equate arrays to pointers. Saves a bunch of hassle.

Comment: arrays are not pointers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
decltype(odd) *arrPtr(int i)
```

This line is saying that you are going to return a pointer to an `int` array of size 5.

When you do

```
return (i % 2) ? odd : even;
```

You are trying to return an `int` array of size 5, *not* a pointer to it. Thus, the `&` in

```
return (i % 2) ? &odd : &even;
```

Is then taking the address of `odd` or `even`, and returning that as a pointer, which is what the function expects you to return.

Note: in C++, you cannot return an array, but you can return pointers.

Also note: The type, when using `&` is `int (*)[5]`, not `int **`, and the return type of the function is essentially `int (*)[5]`, not `int *`

Also also note: As noted in the comments below, typically speaking, if you want to return just an integer array, you can use the return type of `int *`. An `int[5]` will be implicitly cast to a `int *` upon return. The use of the `decltype(odd)` is adding complexity.

Comment: I think I get part of it, but if I get the address of the pointer, it turns out 'int**', how is it possible to assign it to 'int*'?

Comment: @LiuYuan, It is not. The type, when using `&` is `int (*)[5]`, not `int **`, and the return type of the function is `int (*)[5]`, not `int *`

Comment: @LiuYuan `odd` is an array. It is not a pointer. `&odd` is a pointer to an array.

Comment: "You are trying to return an `int` array of size 5". It should be pointed out that very often when code returns an array it is immediately cast to a pointer. If you declared the function as `int *arrPtr(int)`, you could return `odd` or `&odd` and the compiler would figure it out (after all, the address of the first element of the array matches the address of the array). The use of `decltype` caused the additional information about the length of the array to be included in the return type

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it. Really appreciate your time

Comment: Some workarounds for the inability to return a C-style array:  put the array inside a struct wrapper (e.g., `struct Arr5 { int array[5]; };`), use a `std::vector` instead, or use a `std::array`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why '&' here means reference?

It doesn't mean reference here. It is the addressof operator.

> What puzzles me is why there is a need for &. I mean, is it necessary to add a '&'?

Because we are returning a pointer to the array. You get a pointer to the array using the addressof operator.

> It can't be 'address of odd'

It can be, and it is.

> for it will become a second-order pointer.

No. Pointer to array is not a second order pointer. Furthermore, second order pointers would be allowed, so this reasoning doesn't work.

> So it must be a reference.

& means a reference only as a part of a type name (or function qualifier). It never means a reference as part of an expression.

---

> I think I get part of it, but if I get the address of the pointer, it turns out 'int**'

You don't get the address of a pointer, so nothing "turns out `int**`".

You get the address of an array, so you get a pointer to the array.

> how is it possible to assign it to 'int*'?

You don't assign to `int*`. You return the pointer to the array and insert it into an output stream.

Answer (score 1):

This decalres an array:

```
int odd[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
```

The type of the array is `int [5]`. Arrays can decay to a pointer to their first element, that is `&odd[0]`. And thats what is happening when you write: `return (i % 2) ? odd : even;`. The type of the pointer to first element is `int*`. The function, however, returns `decltype(odd) *`, a pointer to an array of `5` integers, that is `int (*) [5]`. And you can get a pointer to the array via the address-of operator: `&odd`.

Arrays are not pointers. Arrays can decay to pointers to their first element. This pointer is not the same as pointer to the whole array. `&odd` and `&odd[0]` point to the same memory location, but they are of different type. The first is a `int (*) [5]`, pointer to array of `5` integers, the latter is `int*`, pointer to `int`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really get my cognitive error: I thought array is a pointer,  but we just use the name of array as a pointer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

decltype() is powerful, & is addressof operator, * is pointer operator:

array/int/pointer are different types, and the way how `decltype()` and `return` "treat" array is different.

```
decltype(odd) *arrPtr(int i)
```

This function would return a type of **pointer** pointing **an
array which consist of 5 integer** that defined by `decltype(odd) *arrPtr`  and `int odd[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};` represented by error msg `int (*) [5]`

so we could not try to return a type of **pointer** pointing **a single element** by `return &odd[0]` or `return odd` as the latter one actually auto converted to a pointer which pointing a **single element**.

> know more about decltype at
> https://smartbear.com/blog/c11-tutorial-let-your-compiler-detect-the-types-of/
> and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

`return &odd;` to return address of an array

or change the function return type as `int* arrPtr` if want to `return odd;`

Answer (score 0):

And this is why you should not learn C to learn C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

std::array<int, 5> odd{1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
std::array<int, 5> even{0, 2, 4, 6, 8};

//return a reference, which is bound to an array with 5 int
std::array<int, 5> &arrPtr(int i)
{
    return (i % 2) ? odd : even;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "odd: " << &odd << std::endl;
    std::cout << "even: " << &even << std::endl;
    std::cout << &arrPtr(3);
}
```

`std::array` arrays that just work like you expect them to work without all the complicated rules about when a C array is an array and when it decays to a pointer. When you need to take the address of it and when not.

`std::array` follows the *behave like an int* rule of thumb. You can return it by value, by pointer or by reference as I do above. Don't return a pointer if a reference will do. That safes the user from having to check for `nullptr` before use.

Note that in `main` I now had to use `&` because what you are trying to print is "where is X located in memory", you want to print the address and not the contents of the array. `std::array` doesn't decay to a pointer like the C array in your example so you have to take the address. Similar for `arrPtr(3)` since that is now a reference instead of a pointer printing the address requires `&`.

Again this is *behaves like an int*. You would use `&i` to print the address of an int, too.